# Kendo Grid MVC can't shrink column beyond some limit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When a user is trying to resize a column (in this case `UnitSellPrice`) to make it smaller...they bounce up against some minimum width that it won't let them shrink more...seems to be around 165px. This is not something I am configuring to my knowledge...in fact, to specify a min width you need to [write custom code](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/apply-minimum-width-during-column-resize), which I'm not doing.

Here is a pic of the most narrow one can make the column by resizing or even specifying the column `.width(100)`. So if they want to shrink the column width to only show "Unit Credit" they can't.

[image]

The reason why the user wants this, is they want to hide part of the column title sometimes and then take a screen snippet and send to their customer.

Is there some base level code in Kendo to limit the min width of a column that I can override?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>
    ()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(l => l.UnitSellPrice).Hidden().Sortable(false);  
    })    
    // Add "Create" command        
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .ColumnMenu()
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
)
```

Comment: You mean like https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api//Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBoundColumnBuilder#minresizablewidthsystemint32 (or https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.minresizablewidth for Kendo UI)?

Comment: you can use columns menu to allow users to choose the active visible columns https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/column-menu

Comment: @FrozenButcher, I am aware of that feature, but I am not trying to hide columns, but to allow the user to resize them, which `.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))` enables them to use, but there seems to be some hard stop on how narrow they can make the column. They can't shrink it to zero width....nor in this case, even less than 200px. See image in my updated question. That is an narrow as one can resize it too for some reason

Comment: @CarstenFranke not sure what you mean. I do have the grid set to resizable via their fluent builder `.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))`. But when resizing the column, it stops you once you get to some unspecified width....you can't shrink it down to zero or 10px...not even 200px in this case....it has some hard coded min width it seems. See pic in updated question.

Comment: I must have copied the wrong link. Search for `MinResizableWidth` on https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridColumnBuilderBase#minresizablewidthsystemint32

Comment: @CarstenFranke thanks...I did see that but my version (2015) doesn't have that option available. In researching this topic, it seems like that option was introduced to prohibit a use from shrinking the column to zero, making it not visible, which is curious, because my version pre-dates this, and I can't make mine go to zero :)

Comment: I try the custom code example that you are not using and if you put 0 at the minimum width you can resize it the way you want. var minColumnWidth = 0;

Comment: Did you finally find a solution to the problem?

Comment: @HaimAbeles no, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example you mentioned. **minColumnWidth = 0**; allow you to reduce the columns the way you intend.

```
$(function(){

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
           dataSource: {
               data: [{foo: "item", bar: "number", baz: "one"}]
           },
           resizable: true
        });

        var minTableWidth;
        var minColumnWidth = 0;
        var th;
        var idx;
        var grid;

        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").resizable.bind("start", function(e) {
           th = $(e.currentTarget).data("th");
           idx = th.index();
           grid = th.closest(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid");
        });

        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").resizable.bind("resize", function(e) {
           if (th.width() >= minColumnWidth) {
              minTableWidth = grid.tbody.closest("table").width();
           }

           if (th.width() < minColumnWidth) {
              // the next line is ONLY needed if Grid scrolling is enabled
              grid.thead.closest("table").width(minTableWidth).children("colgroup").find("col").eq(idx).width(minColumnWidth);

              grid.tbody.closest("table").width(minTableWidth).children("colgroup").find("col").eq(idx).width(minColumnWidth);
           }
        });

    });
```